# VBScript making a call to URL

Tags: vbscript

I need to make a call to url from a vbscript file that is running on a windows server 2012 machine. The script and the domain url are on the same server.  The snippet I tried using is causing an error that I can't see.  Is this snippet correct?  Do I need to include the Microsoft.XMLHTTP library somewhere?  The vbscript file is saved as with an '.asp' extension.   Can the two Dim statements go inside the Sub?

```
 Dim objRequest 
 Dim URL 
 Set objRequest = CreateObject(“Microsoft.XMLHTTP”)      
 URL = “http://example.com/api/Account/List”    
 objRequest.open “POST”, URL , false      
 objRequest.Send      
 Set objRequest = Nothing
```

Here is the complete function call that I attempted to use this snippet.  I put the snipped at the end prior to the End Sub line.

```
Sub addUser(uname, pword, resId)
    If Not FSO.FileExists(PASSWORD_FILE) Then
        Call FileLock("newpass", true)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set passtxt = FSO.OpenTextFile(PASSWORD_FILE, ForAppend, True)
        If (Err) Then
            Response.Write BAD_PERMISSIONS
            Exit Sub
        End If
        passtxt.Close
        Call FileLock("newpass", false)
    End If

    If UserExists(uname) Then
        If (writeLog("bad","ADD-" & DUPLICATE_USER & "|" & GetTimeStamp(Now) & "|" & uname & "|" & resId & "|" & IP_ADDRESS)) Then
            Response.Write DUPLICATE_USER
            Response.End
        Else
            Response.Write BAD_PERMISSIONS
            Response.End
        End If
    End If

    Call FileLock("pass", true)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set passtxt = FSO.OpenTextFile(PASSWORD_FILE, ForAppend, True)
    If (Err) Then
        Response.Write BAD_PERMISSIONS
        Exit Sub
    End If
    passtxt.WriteLine(uname & ":" & pword)
    passtxt.Close
    Call FileLock("pass", false)

    Call FileLock("log", true)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set logtxt = FSO.OpenTextFile(ACTION_LOG_FILE, ForAppend, True)
    If (Err) Then
        Response.Write BAD_PERMISSIONS
        Exit Sub
    End If
    logtxt.WriteLine("ADD-" & SUCCESS & "|" & GetTimeStamp(Now) & "|" & uname & "|" & resId & "|" & IP_ADDRESS)
    logtxt.Close
    Call FileLock("log", false)

    Response.Write SUCCESS
End Sub
```

Comment: the call to the URL does not return anything, it just needs to run.

Comment: Why you can't see an error? Add `On Error Resume Next` at the beginning of the snippet, and at the end something like `Response.Write(Err.Number)` to figure out what is the error. Several `Dim` statements in code will work ok. You are using late binding via `CreateObject()`, and VBScript hasn't early binding, so you have not to include any library. Check in your code if double quote symbols is `"` but not `“`.

Comment: You enabled error handling (`On Error Resume Next`). That hides any error you don't actually handle. Add `If Err Then Response.Write Err.Description & " (0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & ")"` after the line `objRequest.send`. You may also want to check the status of the request (`Response.Write objRequest.Status` or `Response.Write objRequest.StatusText`). And you don't need to enable error handling multiple times. Once enabled the status remains enabled until you either leave the context or disable it (`On Error Goto 0`).

Answer (score 1):

Note the error handling here. I'm testing for COM errors plus the servers response

```
Sub HttpGet
On Error Resume Next
    Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    File.Open "GET", Arg(1), False
    File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
    File.Send
    txt=File.ResponseText
    'Putting in line endings
    Outp.write txt
    If err.number <> 0 then 
        Outp.writeline "" 
        Outp.writeline "Error getting file" 
        Outp.writeline "==================" 
        Outp.writeline "" 
        Outp.writeline "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
        Outp.writeline "Source " & err.source 
        Outp.writeline "" 
        Outp.writeline "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
        Outp.writeline  File.getAllResponseHeaders
        Outp.writeline Arg(1)
    End If
End Sub
```